# Not able start servicemix by running shell script in Jenkins?

Tags: shell, jenkins, apache-servicemix

I have created a shell script to start ServiceMix by calling `bin/start` but it is not starting when it is built from Jenkins. From console it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bin/servicemix instead of bin/start on your custom shell script